# form-data of postman issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, postman

simply i have problem with postman body->form-data the code is good i use express.json parser
and it simply works fine with body->raw and body->urlencooded but i don't know why it doesn't work for formdata

[image: this is postman form data request]

[image: body->raw]

Answer (score 0):

`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: its included in my code too

Comment: `console.log(req.body.email);
console.log(req.body.password);`

and let me see the output

Comment: they are both undefined